# Polymer paper-shadow not being applied

Tags: polymer, web-component

I have issues with paper-shadow in the creation of my application. When I wrap content in a paper-shadow element, the shadow doesn't render no matter what z-index I specify. Developer Tools in Chrome show the paper-shadow element being of size 0x0 pixels.

I am also using a paper-dialog and it is supposed to automatically display a shadow but it also doesn't.

Is there an issue with paper-shadow that I should be aware of?

Comment: showing some code would help us trouble shoot. or better yet if you can reproduce the issue in the plunker or jsbin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this by upgrading to the latest version of Polymer.